# What is the meaning / usage of IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG?

Tags: executable, portability

In the Portable Executable format, there is a directory named IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG. Can someone provide a URL with a good explanation of this directory and its real usage? Why do some apps use this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems originally it was used for some rarely-used features (e.g. LockPrefixTable, I've only seen it in kernel32.dll). These days you generally only see it used for the /safeseh feature (SEHandlerTable/SEHandlerCount).

Comment: Notepad.exe, mspaint.exe and many others contain the IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG directory! Both PeStudio and CFF Explorer show the existence of this directory. It seems like this directory has an new usage.

Comment: As I said, it's used for SafeSEH these days.

Comment: thanks for these details. How do you know this, where does this information - usage of IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG for SEH purposes - comes from?

Comment: thanks, found it: "This provides a list of safe structured exception handlers that the operating system uses during exception dispatching"..